# ReactJS calling two functions with onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I want to call two functions at a time using onClick.

the code I used:

```js
<li
    key={index}
    onClick={this.onClick}
    style={{ color: this.state.Colour }}
>
```

```js
changeColour = (i) => {
        console.log(i);
        this.setState({
            Colour: 'grey',
        });
    };
    crossLine = (event) => {
        const element = event.target;
        element.classList.toggle('crossed-line');
    };
    onClick() {
        this.changeColour();
        this.crossLine();
    }
```

However, it tells me when I run `npm start` and go onto http://localhost:3000:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.changeColour')
```

what is wrong?

---

new edit:

```js
    changeColour = () => {
        this.setState({
            Colour: 'grey',
        });
    };
    crossLine = (event) => {
        const element = event.target;
        element.classList.toggle('crossed-line');
    };
    onButtonClick = () => {
        this.changeColour();
        this.crossLine();
    };
```

```
<li
                                key={index}
                                onClick={this.onButtonClick}
                                style={{ color: this.state.Colour }}
                            >
                                {item}
                </li>
```

sorry for the second one's format..

Comment: `changeColour` is taking a parameter `i` as well as `crossLine`, `event` which you both don't pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in one of the answers, use function binding or just opt for arrow function:

```
<li
    key={index}
    onClick={(event)=>this.onButtonClick(event, index)}
    style={{ color: this.state.Colour }}
>
```

```
    changeColour = (i) => {
        console.log(i);
        this.setState({
            Colour: 'grey',
        });
    };

    crossLine = (event) => {
        const element = event.target;
        element.classList.toggle('crossed-line');
    };

    onButtonClick=(event, index)=> {
        this.changeColour(index);
        this.crossLine(event);
    }
```

Full Example based on question description(more details would have been even helpful :D ):

Output:

[image]

Source code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./style.css";
const list = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"];
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Colour: "black"
    };
  }
  changeColour = i => {
    console.log(i);
    this.setState({
      Colour: "grey",
      index: i
    });
  };

  crossLine = event => {
    const element = event.target;
    console.log(element);
    element.classList.toggle("crossed-line");
  };

  onButtonClick = (event, index) => {
    this.changeColour(index);
    this.crossLine(event);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {list.map((elem, index) => (
            <li
              className={index == this.state.index ? "crossed-line" : null}
              key={index}
              onClick={event => this.onButtonClick(event, index)}
              style={{
                color: index == this.state.index ? this.state.Colour : "black"
              }}
            >
              {elem}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

css:

```
h1,
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}
.crossed-line {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Working app: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3ej9yv?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: this still does not work out right.. ![suffix](https://knowscount-1304485449.cos.ap-shanghai.myqcloud.com/img/Screenshot%202020-12-30%20at%2004.12.42{/suffix})

Comment: please post the remaining section of the code.

Comment: it's fine now! thanks for your help! and my sincere gratitude to all others, of course.

Comment: welcome, also check the updated answer where I have added the working example based on the general vibe that I have got from your question. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

You should define your `onClick` as an arrow function. Otherwise, `this` is undefined unless you `bind` it to the current context.
Also, not related to the `undefined` issue but you should pass params to the function calls.

Answer (score 0):

First: You must bind the function inside the constructor, something like this:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.onButtonClick = this.onButtonClick.bind(this);
}
```

Second: You need to pass the event and the index to the onButtonClick function (*I recommend you use arrow function*):

```
<li
  key={index}
  onClick={(event) => this.onButtonClick(event, index)}
  style={{ color: this.state.Colour }}
>
```

With this, the function onButtonClick can receive the event and thus pass it to the function crossLine, leaving the code similar to this:

```
changeColour = (index) => {
    console.log(index);
    this.setState({
        Colour: 'grey',
    });
};

crossLine = (event) => {
    const element = event.target;
    element.classList.toggle('crossed-line');
};

onButtonClick=(event, index)=> {
    this.changeColour(index);
    this.crossLine(event);
}
```